# Scroll down whole browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

I am making a website and this is my current setup:

http://puu.sh/hU5KJ/421b5aa76d.png

I have 2 main divs, at first the bold one is displayed in full browser window, and after clicking the button, whole window is scrolled down to the 2nd div. The divs are literally placed as in the picture, with the lower div being off screen and the scroll down function is a simple javascript.

My main question here is, can this be done in any alternative way? This feels kinda wrong, also whenever i'm at the lower div and resize the height of the browser window it all gets messed up.

EDIT:

I'd like to have it so that its impossible to scroll by any other means than just those buttons (no arrowkeys, no mouse wheel and preferably no pg down/up buttons). Is that even possible?

HTML buildup:

```
  <div id="wrapper">
  <div id = "overall"></div>
  <div id = "chat"></div>
  </div>
```

With "overall" being the bolded div on the image and "chat" being the lower one. There is plenty of other things i have placed inside of these divs, if you want the full code i can post it, but this is mostly about switching between these 2 only.

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#overall {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#chat {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

And the JS function that scrolls:

```
function scrollDown() {


    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#chat").offset().top
    }, 1000);

}



function scrollUp() {


    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#overall").offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

My knowledge level is low and i guess you can see i only understand the most basic stuff for now, so please explain your answers. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do this without javascript or a better way to do this with javascript?

Comment: I am looking for a better way to do this :) Doesn't matter if it's with javascript or without javascript. My solution gets messed up when browser window is resized, thats one of the things i'd like to eliminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is using the CSS `width:100% & height:100%` properties. These will make sure your element is always sized to the full size of your browser. Even when you resize it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#scroll-down").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#block2").offset().top + 'px'
    }, 'slow');
  })
  $("#scroll-up").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#block1").offset().top + 'px'
    }, 'slow');
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.full-size {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#block1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#block2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper full-size">
  <div class="full-size" id="block1">
    <a href="#block2" id="scroll-down">scroll down</a>
  </div>
  <div class="full-size" id="block2">
    <a href="#block1" id="scroll-up">scroll up</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: included JS smoothscroll

Comment: Hmm, yes, this is one way of doing it. Definitely looks clearer than my code, but i'd like to have the javascript smooth scroll.

Comment: @Nae I've edited my answer to include smoothscrolling

Comment: Yup, this works fine, but is also similar to my previous solution, and if you resize window while on the lower div it will get messed up. 

Also, sorry for not mentioning earlier (gonna edit the post) but i'd like to have it so that its impossible to scroll by any other means than just those buttons (no arrowkeys, no mouse wheel and preferably no pg down/up buttons). Not sure if that is even possible.

Comment: In that case you just need to add an event listener to the window.resize event and do the scrolling again every time the user resizes their browser. 
And of course keep track of which div the user is supposed to be on.

Comment: And for the scrolling you can put `body { overflow:hidden; }`