# Scroll down/up 100% of page - Animated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scroll down/up 100% of height.
Activated by mouse scroll not click.

I tried this, but my page get stuck on bottom.
I'm using wordpress.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        window.scroll(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by "every time", and what should trigger the scrolling: click on a button/link? If yes: which button/link? up and down with the same button or different ones?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll down whole browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350008/scroll-down-whole-browser-window)

Comment: No butons. This is a perfect example of what I search https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

Comment: Ah - well, you have the solution right there in your link...

Comment: I have no idea how to include that on wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
      window.scroll(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
   } else {
      window.scroll(0,0);
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating it:

https://jsbin.com/wodikevare/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In fact this worked. But I want to scroll 100% of the height of page. I edit my question. And this is a demonstration: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

Comment: In that case, your question has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350008/scroll-down-whole-browser-window

Comment: This scroll is activated by click. I want with mouse scroll... Can you help?

Comment: Almost. When I scroll it down to bottom. This is my website https://encurtador.com.br/gkMP7

Comment: I really think you are approaching this the wrong way.  The other example of the site you gave scrolls between different focal elements, not by a fixed height.  I think this is a better approach.

Comment: Well, my site is divided by <section> elements. So, scroll between pre-defined ID or window height should works for me.